# When taking derivatives of power series, why do we shift the index up?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series

For example, if the series starts at n=0, and we take the derivative, the index usually then starts at n=1. This increases as we continue taking derivatives, but why do we need to do this?

I get that if we don't the first term will be 0, but why not include them? Is this simply for convenience of not having to deal with the first few 0 terms?

Comment: You could include the zero terms. But then your reader would have to disregard them in order to understand what was really  happening. Why make it hard for him or her?

Answer (score 3):

Let $$A(x) = \sum_{n=0} ^ \infty a_nx^n = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots$$ be a serie (centered in 0 for this example, if centered in $z$ it would be $\sum_{n=0} ^ \infty a_n(x-z)^n$). Then, if we formally derivate on $x$ (like in a polynomial) we get $$A'(x) = a_1 + 2 a_2 x + 3a_3 x^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0} ^ \infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n.$$

Then it gets a bit messy for the reader, so we can do $k = n+1$ and:

- When $n=0$ we have $k=1$.
- Also we need to know the value of $n$ with respect to $k$, that is $n=k-1$.
- Obviously the upper limit $\infty$ is not affected by this change of variables.

Now we can finally rewrite the serie as: 
$$A'(x) = \sum_{k=1} ^ \infty ka_{k}x^{k-1}.$$

This way we are clearly saying that the first term will be $a_1$. If we would write $A'(x) = \sum_{k=0} ^ \infty ka_{k}x^{k-1}$ the reader needs to realize that the first term is multiplied by 0 so its null...

For the $i$-th derivative it can be shown (by induction) that

$$A^{(i)}(x) = \sum_{k=i} ^ \infty (k·(k-1)\cdots(k-i+1))a_{k}x^{k-i},$$

with $k=n+i$. Here, if we would write $A^{(i)}(x) = \sum_{k=0} ^ \infty (k·(k-1)\cdots(k-i+1))a_{k}x^{k-i}$, when $k=0$ the term is 0, when $k=1$ the term is 0 cause $k-1$ is 0 and so on... Hard and messy to know when the series truly starts, right?

Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly legit (and common, I don't know what has influenced your perception) to reindex as you see fit:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1}= 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1) a_{k+1} x^k
$$

Comment: My question comes from the change you made between the second and third terms. Why can't the second term have a k=0 without changing the k in the series to a (k+1)?

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity You can use $k=0$, but since $0$ times anything is $0$, we immediately get the following $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^0 k a_k x^{k-1} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1}= 0 +   \sum_{k=1}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1} $. And then $  \sum_{k=1}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1) a_{k+1} x^k$ . Also $k=0$ introduces another subtle problem. If we evaluate  $\sum_{k=0}^0 k a_k x^{k-1} = 0 a_k x^{0-1} $ we get a discontinuity at $x=0$, because of division by zero, which didn't exist in the original series for any $x$.